# Ninject Failing Silently

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I am evaluating Ninject for a project, and the only issue I have had with it is that it fails silently on property injection.  If I call

```
Kernel.Get<ISomething>();
```

on a faulty binding, it will fail with an exception, but if I use property injection:

```
[Inject]
public ISomething Something { get; set;}
```

it fails silently.  I don't know there's an issue until I go to use the reference and it is null.  Any ideas on how to make this fail with an exception?

Comment: Does it fail silently if you `Kernel.Get<TheTypeThatHasTheProperty>()` ? Think it does but just wanted to make sure you're not expecting `new` to work differently because Ninject is around. The recommended approach is to prefer ctor injection (see the ninject wiki) as there's absolutely no confusion when you use that.

Comment: Yes Ruben is right. Property Injection creates the same exception as constructor injection if a binding is missing. But constructor injection should be prefered whenever possible anyway.

Comment: For clarity, that means I'm wrong in my guess above that it might not. You need to use  `[Optional]` if you want to signal that you're not fussed as to whether a specific item is resolvable and are happy to have it be left ass null. There's also a way to switch on 'Inject null semantics' (recent question around here covers that), but that's a different matter. BTW highly recommend reading @Mark Seeman's top answers for advice on how to best use DI

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not correct. Although constructor injection is preferred (as Remo comments), if Ninject sees an `[Inject]` property attribute and doesn't have a binding, it *will* throw an `ActivationException`.

Here's an example.

Dependency:

```
public interface IHello
{
    void SayHello();
}

public class Hello : IHello
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Dependent class:

```
public class MyApp : IApp
{
    public virtual void Run()
    {
        Hello.SayHello();
    }

    [Inject]
    public IHello Hello { get; set; }
}
```

Main Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<MyApp>().ToSelf();
        //kernel.Bind<IHello>().To<Hello>();
        var app = kernel.Get<MyApp>();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

If you run this, you will get the following exception:

```
Error activating IHello  
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.  
Activation path:  
  2) Injection of dependency IHello into property Hello of type MyApp  
  1) Request for MyApp
```

Uncomment the `kernel.Bind<IHello>().To<Hello>()` line above and it will run correctly.

As Ruben comments, Ninject will only "fail silently" if you also add `[Optional]` to the `[Inject]`-ed property.  Which is because you've now told Ninject that a missing binding is *not* a failure, but an expected condition.  Otherwise, property injection works exactly the same as constructor injection.

---

I suspect that you may be making a common mistake for people who are new to dependency injection: instantiating a dependent class (with an `[Inject]`ed property) with `new` and assuming that the injection "just happens". It doesn't work that way.

In order for Ninject or any other DI library to work its magic, **you must instantiate the *container* with the binding root** - in other words, whichever class *contains* the `Something` property must itself be created using `kernel.Get<ClassContainingSomething>()`.